# spacy.load error: RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration

Tags: python, runtime-error, spacy

I am loading a spaCy model as part of a step in my Dataflow streaming pipeline. To load the pre-downloaded spaCy model for a specific language I am using
`nlp_model = spacy.load(SPACY_KEYS[lang])`
where SPACY_KEYS is a dictionary containing the names of the models for each language (e.g. 'en': 'en_core_web_sm').

This works without any issues for the majority of the jobs run by the pipeline, but for a few iterations I am getting the following error:

```
Error message from worker: generic::unknown: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 1232, in apache_beam.runners.common.DoFnRunner.process
  File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 752, in apache_beam.runners.common.PerWindowInvoker.invoke_process
  File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 870, in apache_beam.runners.common.PerWindowInvoker._invoke_process_per_window
  File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 1368, in apache_beam.runners.common._OutputProcessor.process_outputs
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/submodules/entities_and_pii_removal.py", line 259, in entities_and_PII
    nlp_model = spacy.load(SPACY_KEYS[lang])  # load spacy model
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/spacy/__init__.py", line 52, in load
    name, vocab=vocab, disable=disable, exclude=exclude, config=config
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/spacy/util.py", line 420, in load_model
    return load_model_from_package(name, **kwargs)  # type: ignore[arg-type]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/spacy/util.py", line 453, in load_model_from_package
    return cls.load(vocab=vocab, disable=disable, exclude=exclude, config=config)  # type: ignore[attr-defined]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/de_core_news_sm/__init__.py", line 10, in load
    return load_model_from_init_py(__file__, **overrides)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/spacy/util.py", line 621, in load_model_from_init_py
    config=config,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/spacy/util.py", line 489, in load_model_from_path
    return nlp.from_disk(model_path, exclude=exclude, overrides=overrides)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/spacy/language.py", line 2042, in from_disk
    util.from_disk(path, deserializers, exclude)  # type: ignore[arg-type]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/spacy/util.py", line 1299, in from_disk
    reader(path / key)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/spacy/language.py", line 2037, in <lambda>
    p, exclude=["vocab"]
  File "spacy/pipeline/trainable_pipe.pyx", line 343, in spacy.pipeline.trainable_pipe.TrainablePipe.from_disk
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/spacy/util.py", line 1299, in from_disk
    reader(path / key)
  File "spacy/pipeline/trainable_pipe.pyx", line 333, in spacy.pipeline.trainable_pipe.TrainablePipe.from_disk.load_model
  File "spacy/pipeline/trainable_pipe.pyx", line 334, in spacy.pipeline.trainable_pipe.TrainablePipe.from_disk.load_model
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/thinc/model.py", line 593, in from_bytes
    return self.from_dict(msg)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/thinc/model.py", line 624, in from_dict
    loaded_value = deserialize_attr(default_value, value, attr, node)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/functools.py", line 840, in wrapper
    return dispatch(args[0].__class__)(*args, **kw)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/thinc/model.py", line 804, in deserialize_attr
    return srsly.msgpack_loads(value)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/srsly/_msgpack_api.py", line 27, in msgpack_loads
    msg = msgpack.loads(data, raw=False, use_list=use_list)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/srsly/msgpack/__init__.py", line 76, in unpackb
    for decoder in msgpack_decoders.get_all().values():
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/catalogue/__init__.py", line 110, in get_all
    for keys, value in REGISTRY.items():
RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration
```

I have not been able to identify the cause of this problem. Is there a way of getting around it?

Comment: This probably requires modifications to `catalogue`. It would make sense to open an issue: https://github.com/explosion/catalogue/